# Mock and argument capture in the same method call

Tags: java, spring, unit-testing, junit, mockito

I have the the following method/class

```
public class SomeServiceImpl{

    @Value("${someUrl}")
    private String someUrl;

    @Autowired
    private RestClientUtil restClientUtil;

    @Autowired
    private ObjectMapper objectMapper;

    public Some getSomeData(String place,String date) throws Exception{

        String response = null;
        someUrl = someUrl+ "?location="+place+"+date=+"+date;
        try {
            response = restClientUtil.getHttpCall(null, null, someUrl, null);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            throw new Exception("Some Data Api call failed ");
        }

        Some some = objectMapper.readValue(response,Some.class);

        return some;
    }
}
```

Below is the corresponding test case i tried writing using spring boot test mockito framework.

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest
@TestPropertySource(properties={"someUrl = http://www.some_url.com"})
public class SomeServiceImplTests {

    @Value("${someUrl}")
    private String someUrl;

    @MockBean
    private RestClientUtil mockRestClientUtil;

    @MockBean
    private ObjectMapper mockObjectMapper;

    @Autowired
    private SomeServiceImpl someServiceImpl;



    @Test
    public void testGetSomeData() throws Exception{
        String place = "NewYork";
        Date date = new Date();
        String response = "xyz";
        Some  some = new Some();
        String username=  null;
        String password=  null;
        Map<String,String> headerMap = null;

        ArgumentCaptor<String> userNameCaptor = ArgumentCaptor.forClass(String.class);
        ArgumentCaptor<String> passwordCaptor = ArgumentCaptor.forClass(String.class);
        ArgumentCaptor<String> urlCaptor = ArgumentCaptor.forClass(String.class);
        ArgumentCaptor<Map<String,String>> headerCaptor = ArgumentCaptor.forClass(Map.class);

        String capusername = userNameCaptor.capture();
        String cappassword = passwordCaptor.capture();
        String capurl = urlCaptor.capture();
        Map<String,String> capHeader = headerCaptor.capture();



        when(mockRestClientUtil.getHttpCall(capusername,cappassword,capurl,capHeader)).thenReturn(response);

        ArgumentCaptor<String> responseCaptor = ArgumentCaptor.forClass(String.class);
        String capresponse = responseCaptor.capture();
        when(mockObjectMapper.readValue(capresponse,eq(Some.class))).thenReturn(some);

        assertEquals(some,someServiceImpl.getSomeData(place,date.toString()));


        verify(mockRestClientUtil, times(1)).getHttpCall(capusername,cappassword,capurl,capHeader);
        verify(mockObjectMapper,times(1)).readValue(capresponse, eq(Some.class));




        assertEquals(response,capresponse);
        assertEquals(username,capusername);
        assertEquals(password,cappassword);
        assertEquals(someUrl+ "?location="+place+"+date=+"+date,urlCaptor.getValue());
        assertEquals(headerMap,capHeader);
    }
}
```

I am not able to capture and verify the arguments to httpcall method and subsequesntly verify the entire getSomeData method.

I am currently facing the following exception.

```
Argument(s) are different! Wanted:
restClientUtil bean.getHttpCall(
    null,
    null,
    null,
    null
);
-> at com.x.x.service.impl.SomeServiceImplTests.testGetSomeData(SomeServiceImplTests.java:83)
Actual invocation has different arguments:
restClientUtil bean.getHttpCall(
    null,
    null,
    "http://www.some_url.com?location=NewYork+date=+Sat Aug 18 02:15:28 IST 2018",
    null
);
-> at com.x.x.service.impl.SomeServiceImpl.getSomeData(SomeServiceImpl.java:36)

    at com.x.x.service.impl.SomeServiceImplTests.testGetSomeData(SomeServiceImplTests.java:83)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestExecutionCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestExecutionCallbacks.java:73)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestExecutionCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestExecutionCallbacks.java:83)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.java:75)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.java:86)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.SpringRepeat.evaluate(SpringRepeat.java:84)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:251)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:97)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:70)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:190)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:86)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:459)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:678)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:382)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:192)
```

I tried reordering verify, capture and assert statements to try my luck.. Nothing worked!

Need help. 
Thanks

Comment: You're trying to capture before the method is invoked.  In this case there's no need to capture the parameters to `mockRestClientUtil`.  Simply `when(mockRestClientUtil.getHttpCall(null,null,someUrl,null)).thenReturn(response)`.  If it's not invoked with those parameter values then the result will be `null` and the verify will fail.

Answer (score 2):

The normal approach is to deal with the mocking, then do the verify with capturing, and then deal with the assertions.

Something like (not tested, and didn't want to use as many arguments as you):

```
@Test
public void testThing() {
    final String response = "Pong";
    final String arg = "Ping";

    doReturn(response).when(mockService).call(arg);

    serviceWhichCallsMockService.triggerPing();

    final ArgumentCaptor<String> captor = ArgumentCaptor.forClass(String.class);

    verify(mockService).call(captor.capture());

    final String receivedArg = captor.getValue();

    // Confirms 'triggerPing' passed 'Ping' to your 'mockService'
    assertEquals(arg, receivedArg);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To use Argument captor follow below steps :

1. `ArgumentCaptor<String> captor = ArgumentCaptor.forClass(String.class);`
2. pass the argument cpator to method for which you're trying to capture the argument like below.

   `when(mock.method(any(), captor.capture(), any()))`
3. Make the actual call to the public method.

   `testclass.method();`
4. Do assert of the captured argument.
   `assertEquals("expected", captor.getValue());`